# Is there something wrong with my for loop causing it to display incorrect asterisks on screen?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

I've been try to debug my for loop but can't seem to see find the problem why my for loop is not working as it displays the asterisks in wrong formatting. What is wrong in my loop, is initialisation or incorrect conditions? Cause I've been trying to do all sorts for a few hours and can't seem to get anywhere.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{

   int inp;

   printf("Enter an integer> \n");
   scanf("%d", &inp);

   if (inp >=1)
   {
      int i, space, j;

      for (i=1; i<=inp; i++)
      { 
         for (space=1; space<=inp-i; space++)
         {
            printf(" ");
         }
      }

      for (j=0; j<=(2*i)-1; j++)
      {
         printf("*");
      }
      printf("\n");
   }

   if (inp <=0)
   {
      printf("Input must be greater or equal to 1\n");
   }

   return 0;

 }
```

[Screenshot of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwXCH.png)
[Here's the output I'm meant to be getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nC0uN.png)
The output I am getting is a straight line of asterisks with the amount of asterisks dynamically changing depending on the number I am inputting. I should be getting a triangle as shown in the above screenshot but I'm not.

**Desired Output:**

```
     *
    ***
   *****
  *******
```

Comment: Show the code expected and actual outputs in your question instead of providing references.

Comment: Post actual code.  (No one is going to re-type your code based on an image)

Comment: Please don't add a screenshot of the code

Comment: Ok I will do it now

Comment: Code has been added in now, please give me some help on where I went wrong?

Comment: What output are you getting?

Comment: A straight line of asterisks.

Comment: Please show what you are getting, and what is wrong with it or what you wanted to get

Comment: In the question, please.

Comment: Yes added the requested info.

Comment: Your code works if you put the `}`in the correct position

Comment: Where should that be placed, because I have been playing around with the braces but came out with a vertical line of asterisks when I did that.

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...). Improve the code to get no warnings. Then [use the `gdb` debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) to understand what is wrong

Comment: I compiled with -Wall and -Werror options, and there were no errors found, but when I try to debug and played around with the braces, the output changed so I assumed it was the culprit.

Comment: Are really downvoters willing to spend their rep points downvoting to exclude a newbie with rep of 1 from SO ? Those guys are giving SO a bad reputation. Even John Skeet considered quitting SO because of them! I agree the question is not that good, but downvoting like that is just mean.

Comment: @kriss:  Look at the edit history:  The original question was ***horrible*** with images of code and a total lack of detail about what the program was supposed to do.  The early downvotes were completely warranted.   I've now retracted mine.

Comment: @abelenky: ok, I see. Still there is something broken if our current normal behavior exclude newbies from the start. Should be discussed on meta. Maybe something like a grace delay for newbies could work (I mean: downvoting questions, but not user until some level is reached).

Comment: Hello guys, I am now try to fix the indentation of position of the triangles, basically the pattern displays correctly after applying the solutions you guys suggested to me, how would I let say shift the rows over by two spaces?

Comment: It is not appropriate to extend your question in comments.   Edit your original question to expand it, or ask an entirely new question.

Answer (score 2):

Why you make it so complicated?

Now with padding columns, if you want to indent and shift the rows over:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int height;
    int pad;
    puts("Enter an integer> \n");
    scanf("%d", &height);

    puts("Enter padding columns> \n");
    scanf("%d", &pad);

    for(int i=0; i < height; ++i)
    {
        printf("%*s%*.*s\n", pad, "", height+i, 2*i+1, "********************");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

***[IDEOne Link](https://ideone.com/iGZvU8)***

**Output**
*(with `height = 6;` and `pad = 3;`)*

```
Success #stdin #stdout 0s 4384KB
        *
       ***
      *****
     *******
    *********
   ***********
```

Comment: Because I have to use if statements depending on certain numbers like let's say -1 then it has to print out that the number must be larger than 1. Also I cannot hardcode values in.

Comment: You just have to ask it before the for loop and make an if statement to check it and exit with the correct code and message if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

there were several mistakes in the code

here is what i did to fix it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int inp;

    printf("Enter an interger> \n");
    scanf("%d", &inp);
    printf( "\nYou entered:  %d\n\n",  inp);

    if (inp >= 1) {
        int i, space, j;

        for (i = 1; i <= inp; i++) {

            for (space = i; space <= inp -1; space++) {
                printf(" ");
            }
            for (j = 1; j <= (2 * i) - 1; j++) {
                printf("*");
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }

    if (inp <= 0) {
        printf("Input must be greater or equal to 1\n");
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Ok thank you for your help, will give it go and try out myself, that's part of the learning process :)

Comment: How would I move everything by two spacebars? Cause the initial asterisk has to be aligned right under letter a of the word "an"

Answer (score 0):

These loops

```
 for (i=1; i<=inp; i++)
 { 
 for (space=1; space<=inp-i; space++)
 {
  printf(" ");
 }
 }
```

mean outputting spaces `( inp - 1 ) + ( inp - 2 ) + ... + 1` times that does not make sense.

And this for loop

```
 for (j=0; j<=(2*i)-1; j++)
 {
 printf("*");
 }
```

must be inside this for loop

```
for (i=1; i<=inp; i++)
```

That is the loops should look at least like

```
 for (i=1; i<=inp; i++)
 { 
 for (space=1; space<=inp-i; space++)
 {
  printf(" ");
 }
// } <-- removed

 for (j=1; j<=(2*i)-1; j++)
 //   ^^^^
 {
 printf("*");
 }
 printf("\n");
 }
```

I can suggest the following solution.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    const char c = '*';

    while ( 1 )
    {
        printf( "Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): " );

        int n;

        if ( scanf( "%d", &n ) != 1 || n < 1 ) break;

        putchar( '\n' );

        for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        {
            printf( "%*c", n - i, c );
            for ( unsigned int j = 0; j < 2 * i; j++ ) putchar( c );
            putchar( '\n' );
        }

        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 5

    *
   ***
  *****
 *******
*********

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 4

   *
  ***
 *****
*******

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 3

  *
 ***
*****

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 2

 *
***

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 1

*

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 0
```

If you want to use a loop to output spaces then the program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    const char c = '*';

    while ( 1 )
    {
        printf( "Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): " );

        int n;

        if ( scanf( "%d", &n ) != 1 || n < 1 ) break;

        putchar( '\n' );

        for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        {
            for ( unsigned int j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++ ) putchar( ' ' );
            for ( unsigned int j = 0; j < 2 * i + 1; j++ ) putchar( c );
            putchar( '\n' );
        }

        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look the same way as it is shown above.

Take into account that it is a bad idea to use the following form of a for loop that uses the operator `<=` in the condition as for example

```
for (i=1; i<=inp; i++)
```

Such a loop has a potential bug when inp is equal to `INT_MAX`.

It is better to use the operator `<` in the condition and set initial value of the index to 0.

```
for ( i = 0; i < inp; i++ )
```

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with your code is that you **didn't indented it properly**. Henceforth you missed that the second loop drawing stars isn't *inside* the external loop.

As you also din't declared variables as close as possible to use site (but that is more a C++ habit than a C one), the compiler also din't warned you about i being out of scope.

There is also a minor issue about the end range of the *j* loop. If you start your loop at zero, you should end it using inferior strict not inferior or equal (or your count is of by one). I usually stick as far as possible to loop starting at zero and strict final condition. It's simpler and match array bound convention.

Beyond that your code is indeed a bit too complicated but not that bad.

After fixing it would become something like that:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int inp;
    printf("Enter an integer> \n");
    scanf("%d", &inp);
    printf("\n");

    if (inp >=1)
    {
        for (int i=0; i < inp; i++) { 
             for (int space = 0; space< inp-i; space++) {
                printf(" ");
             }
            for (int j=0; j < 2*i+1 ; j++){
                printf("*");
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }

    if (inp <=0){
        printf("Input must be greater or equal to 1\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```